# Check if a floating point type is a superset of another floating point type

Tags: c++, floating-point, compile-time, c++23

Is there a standard conform and portable way to check at compile time, if all values of one floating point type can be represented within another floating point type? Please also consider upcoming types like `std::bfloat16_t`.

I found this:

- A float is a guaranteed subset of double
- A double is a guaranteed subset of long double
- And of course a float is a guaranteed subset of a long double

I could specialize a predicate at least for these combinations.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Floating-point_types):

> long double — extended precision floating-point type. Matches IEEE-754
> binary128 format if supported, otherwise matches IEEE-754
> binary64-extended format if supported, otherwise matches some
> non-IEEE-754 extended floating-point format as long as its precision
> is better than binary64 and range is at least as good as binary64,
> otherwise matches IEEE-754 binary64 format.

If I read this correctly, long double can at least represent all values of IEEE-754 binary64.
This information could be used to compare the fixed types with long double. Of course only if cppreference is right.

Comment: You could check `digits` and `max_exponent`, etc from `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits. But that still makes it hard to check if e.g. converting an integer to a floating point type is lossless (also cases of different radix could be difficult).

Comment: Integer to Floating point conversions are currently not relevant for me. But of course in general this is interesting, too.

Comment: It is always guaranteed in the chain `float` -> `double` -> `long double` by the C++ standard. For the extended types it is specified exactly by IEEE 754 / ISO 60559. But I don't think you can reliably test this between the standard and extended types. The standard types have almost no specification in the C++ standard. Maybe if they declare to be IEEE 754-conforming via `std::numeric_limits::is_iec559`.

Comment: There is a general naive solution at runtime that is not practical: Use `std::nextafter` and the limits from `std::numeric_limits` to iterate over _all_ representable values of the standard types and compare with the standardized representable values of the extended types. That is a direct comparison of the set of representable values.

Comment: std::nextafter is constexpr since C++23. So it could be used inside a consteval function. But it would be still horrible because developer time is also valuable.

Comment: @MartinFehrs Yes true, I overlooked that. But I don't see what cppreference's quote in your question is based on.

Comment: I got it from here. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Floating-point_types.  The relevant part is "otherwise matches IEEE-754 binary64 format."

Comment: @MartinFehrs Yes, but I see no basis for the statements in the C++ standard draft.

Comment: Do you mean, that you can't find this in the standard? Sorry my English isn't goo enough to fully understand you.

Comment: @MartinFehrs Yes, I can't find this in the standard.

Comment: I think it is derived from the requirements in ISO C's Annex F, which only applies if `__STDC_IEC_60559_BFP__`/`__STDC_IEC_559__` are set by the compiler, i.e. if the compiler declares the floating point types to be IEEE 754-conforming / conforming to the annex.

Comment: @chtz The C standard allows floating-point types to contain values that are not floating-point values (such as NaN, infinities, but also real values that would not normally be representable), and I suppose that this is the same in C++ for consistency. In such a case, checking `digits` and `max_exponent` would not be sufficient, but there's isn't really anything you can do automatically. A good example is IBM long double (a.k.a. double-double) vs binary128 (a.k.a. quadruple precision).